# Validação de data no VBA

Tags: excel-vba, validação

Olá.

Tenho uma Planilha que na célula "C16" possui uma data. Eu preciso que a Macro faça uma validação do mês e do ano que está inserido na célula "C16". Se o mês e o ano na célula "C16" já estiver na coluna A da Planilha2, mostrar erro. Alguém pode me ajudar?

Answer (score -1):

Você não precisa de uma macro, pode fazer isso com uma fórmula. Tente aplicar a seguinte validação.

Selecione o intervalo que contém as datas a serem validadas (no seu caso, `C16`, mas pode ser um intervalo maior). Com a seleção ativa, vá ao menu `Dados` -> Grupo `Ferramentas de Dados` -> Botão `Validação de Dados`. Na caixa de diálogo `Validação de dados`, na aba `Configurações`, na opção `Permitir` selecione `Personalizado` e, na caixa de texto `Fórmula`, use a seguinte fórmula. Se você resolver aplicar validação a outras células da coluna, `C16` tem que ser substituído pela célula mais de cima do intervalo que você quer validar.

```
=CONT.SES(Planilha2!$A:$A;">="&FIMMÊS(C16;-1)+1;Planilha2!$A:$A;"<="&FIMMÊS(C16;0))>0
```

Answer (score -2):

Olha, o ideal que você poste mais informações para tentar entender melhor, porém, como você disse planilha, tenta algo assim:

=PROCV(valor_procurado;matriz_tabela;nume_indice_coluna;procurar_intervalo).

Comment: Desculpe, não fui muito claro mesmo.

Comment: Seguinte.


Na célula "C16" da Planilha1, o usuário precisa inserir uma data (Exemplo: 01/01/2022).
Na coluna "A" da planilha2, existe algumas datas.

Eu preciso de um código de validação. Preciso validar que se tiver uma data inserida na célula "C16"  com o mês e o ano apenas, igual na coluna "A" da Planilha2, mostre algum erro. Exemplo: Na coluna "A" da planilha2 tem uma data 01/04/2022, se o usuário tentar colocar qualquer dia, com este mês e ano (no caso 04 e 2022) na célula "C16" da Planilha1, o excel precisa mostrar um erro.

Answer (score -2):

Se deseja que o VBA faça essa crítica, segue uma alternativa utilizando o evento Change da planilha:

```
    Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim rngDigitação As Excel.Range
    Dim rngDatas As Excel.Range
    Dim intMês As Integer
    Dim intAno As Integer
    Dim intData As Integer

    Set rngDigitação = Range("rngDigitação")
    Set rngDatas = Range("rngDatas")

    intMês = Month(rngDigitação.Value)
    intAno = Year(rngDigitação.Value)

    For intData = 1 To rngDatas.Cells.Count
        If Year(rngDatas(intData)) = intAno Then
            If Month(rngDatas(intData)) = intMês Then
                MsgBox "A combinação mês/ano já existe (" & _
                       Format(intMês, "00") & "/" & Format(intAno, "0000") & ")", _
                       vbOKOnly, "Tente outra vez"
                rngDigitação = ""
            End If
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

Acesse o evento Change da guia de planilha no VBE (abrindo-o teclando ALT + F11 no Excel) para, em seguida, clicar no nome da guia desejada na janela 'Project Explorer' (ex.: Planilha1) e, finalmente, na Caixa de Texto onde está exibido '(Geral)'. Escolha 'Worksheet' e, em seguida, estarão disponíveis os diversos eventos de planilha, na Caixa de Listagem de Eventos à direita desta. Escolha 'Change' e cole aí o código.
Destaco que os intervalos de células envolvidas nos cálculos estão nomeados. Para nomear uma célula, ou um grupo de células, selecione-as e, em seguida, clique na Caixa de Nomes e digite um nome para esse conjunto de células.
Ao final do alerta a macro limpa o conteúdo da entrada feita. Adapte à sua realidade. Os intervalos nomeados são previamente definidos manualmente.

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).